# Get values from JSON data [object]

Tags: javascript, c#, json

[debugging screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33h1A.jpg)

```js
$.ajax({
    url: postUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "id": num },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {


        $.each(data, function (id, allFollowers) {
            result += 'Title : ' + **data** + '<br/>';
        });
```

I've tried: data.allFollowers[0].screeName, data[0].allFollowers[0].screeName...

I can see these values exist here in debug mode, however it returns a null error..?

Comment: Don't know if you made this mistake while actually trying it, but you're missing a 'n' in screeName

Comment: put `debugger;` in top of success function on line 8 and debug with inspect element to see what is coming from server.

Comment: Hello Hossein, did you see the screenshot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, I'm *assuming* the data somewhat looks like this:

```
//data is an object, with an array of allFollowers objects
var data = {
  "allFollowers": [{
      "AlternateText": "no photo",
      "profileImage": "http://foo.com/foo",
      "screenName": "foo",
      "userID": 15785100
    },
    {
      "AlternateText": "no photo",
      "profileImage": "http://bar.com/bar",
      "screenName": "bar",
      "userID": 12345678
    }

  ]
};
```

You're iterating on `data` only/instead of its child array (`allFollowers`). So you'll have to go one level deeper:

```
$.each(data, function(key, obj) {   
  $.each(obj, function(i, value){
    console.log("screen name %i: %o, User ID: %o", i, value.screenName, value.userID);
  })
})
```

Console:

```
screen name 0: "foo", User ID: 15785100
screen name 1: "bar", User ID: 12345678
```

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is about using `$.each` function. You should refer to your data using some code like:

```
    $.each(data, function (id, follower) {
        result += 'Title : ' + follower + '<br/>';
    });
```

For more info refer to this [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: I've seen screenshot before I send my post. I know what the data is but as i got the issue you want to iterate throw data and my code does it. If i'm wrong, so  why you are using `$.each` function?